# How can I make passing a list with just one value to an other method less verbose

Tags: java, arraylist

If I have a method like this

```
private void setStringList(List<String> aList) { ... }
```

Then this is obviously possible

```
private void testOnly() {
    List<String> myDummyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myDummyList.add("someValue");
    setStringList(myDummyList);
}
```

but is there a way to make it less verbose like this

```
private void testOnly2() {        
    setStringList(new ArrayList<String>().add("someValue"));
}
```

I know above is compilation error but just showing to demonstrate what I want to achieve just to make it less verbose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
private void testOnly2() {        
    setStringList(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("someValue")));
}
```

or, depending on what you use the argument for in `setStringList`:

```
private void testOnly2() {        
    setStringList(Arrays.asList("someValue"));
}
```

Another option is to use an instance-initializer, like this:

```
private void testOnly2() {
    setStringList(new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("someValue");
    }});
}
```

(this creates an anonymous subclass of ArrayList though.)

Comment: Thanks so which is better option . Second one looks best in simplicity.

Comment: Yes. The second option doesn't create an ArrayList though. It creates a list which you can't add or remove elements from. Read up on [java.util.Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Comment: `Collections.singletonList` is better than any of these options unless the class with `setStringList` needs the list to be mutable and isn't defensively copying the input list.

Answer (score 6):

As well as the suggestions from aioobe which just use the JDK, [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) offers various options, including:

```
setStringList(Lists.newArrayList("someValue"));

setStringList(ImmutableList.of("someValue"));
```

Comment: Additionally, the jdk has Collections.singletonList(), although I also prefer guava's immutable types where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
private void testOnly2() {        
  setStringList(Collections.singletonList("someValue"));
}
```